# Show that A is a field which has $9$ elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, finite-fields

For $A=\left\{\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
a&b\\
{ - b}&a
\end{array}} \right) | a,b\in\mathbb{Z/3Z}\right\}$ . Show that A is a field which has $9$ elements .  $(A^*, .)$ is a cyclic group $G$ and $|G|=8$.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}/3$?

Comment: @E.Costa, just another notation for $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Ok, you made a mess of this question: what is $\,G\,$ ? Apparently $\,G:=A^*:=A-\{0\}\,$ ...? We also usually write $\,\Bbb F_3:=\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z\,$ and not merely $\,\Bbb Z/3\,$ , though I've seen this notation before.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z/3}=\{\overline{0};\overline{1};\overline{2}\}$

Comment: Do you know the definition of a field? Have you tried checking that the set $A$ with the obvious operations (matrix addition and multiplication) satisfy the field axioms? Have you constructed a multiplication table for $A^* = A \setminus \{ 0 \}$?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $\ $ Use the following to show $\rm\: A\,\cong\, \Bbb F_3{\bf [}\,{\it i}\:{\bf ]}\, \cong\, \Bbb F_3{\bf [}x{\bf ]}/(x^2\!+1)$

$${\bf i}\, = \left[\begin{array}{rr} 0 & 1\\ -1 & 0\end{array}\right]\ \Rightarrow\,\ {\bf i}^2 =\, -1 ,\qquad \left[\begin{array}{rr} \rm a &\rm b\\ \rm -b &\rm a\end{array}\right]\, =\rm \,\ a + b\ {\bf i}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$$(1)\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;|A|=3^2=9$$

$$(2)\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\forall \;0\neq\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\\!\!-b&a\end{pmatrix}\in A\;,\;\;\text{ also}\;\;\frac{1}{a^2+b^2}\begin{pmatrix}a&\!\!-b\\b&a\end{pmatrix}\in A$$

$$(3)\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\forall\;X,Y\in A\;,\;\;\;XY=YX\ldots$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.**

There is only one isomorphism class of finite field for every prime power $p^e$, so if you don't want to make a multiplication table or check the axioms one by one, you may instead construct a ring homomorphism from your $A$ to the usual presentation of $\displaystyle\mathbb{F}_9=\frac{\mathbb{F}_3[x]}{\langle x^2+x+2\rangle}$.  Everything in there looks like $a_0+a_1x$ and the multiplication is done reduced modulo $ x^2+x+2$, so all you need to do is figure out which elements you'll send to the element $1$ (i.e. $a_0=1,a_1=0$) and which to the element $x$ ($a_0=0,a_1=1$).  The way the matrices multiply is suggestive of how you could make this isomorphism.

Comment: We have order G equal the number $(a,b)$ with $a,b\in \mathbb{F_3}$ so $|G|=9$.

Comment: @Hungnguyen It's true that $|\mathbb{F}_9|=9$, but the element $(0,0)$ is not in the multiplicative group $\mathbb{F}_9^\star$.  So $|\mathbb{F}_9^\star|=8$.